# Casper.js WaitFor X or Y

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I now can trigger set of actions when 'AM' appears on the site. How do I do it if I need either 'AM' or 'PM' to trigger the action.

```
casper.waitForText('AM', function() {
    this.echo('found AM');
    //do stuff

});
```

Comment: Artjom, I haven't had a chance to try it yet. Will let you know as soon as I'll test it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`casper.waitForText()` supports also regular expressions:

```
casper.waitForText(/[AP]M/, function(){
    this.echo('found [AP]M');
});
```